# My upgrade code won't work - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, script, install-script

### Updated Config

in my config I have now (and it seems to see the script but then once I run it it gives me only a echo "Creating new column ......" then stop and does nothing):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <EDPA_Adpan>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </EDPA_Adpan>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <edpa_adpan>
            <class>EDPA_Adpan_Block</class>
        </edpa_adpan>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <edpa_adpan>
            <class>EDPA_Adpan_Helper</class>
        </edpa_adpan>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
        <adpan_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>EDPA_Adpan</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </adpan_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <EDPA_Adpan before="Mage_Adminhtml">EDPA_Adpan_Adminhtml</EDPA_Adpan>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <edpa_adpan>
                <file>edpa/adpan.xml</file>
            </edpa_adpan>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

then in mysql4-upgrade-0.0.4-0.0.5

```
echo 'Creating new column ......';
/* @var $this Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */ 
// Add an extra column to the eav/catalog_products table:
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer-
getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity '),
'lo',
array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    'nullable' => false,
    'default' => '0',
    'comment' => 'Price reduction lo level (%)'
));
$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity '),
'hi',
array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    'nullable' => false,
    'default' => '100',
    'comment' => 'Price reduction hi level (%)'
));$installer->endSetup();
```

expecting it will stop because there is die(); in a code but it doesn't
It also updating record in core_resource to the new version but table is not altered, can anyone explain me why ? or maybe the table name is wrong ?
These new columns should appear in catalog_products_entity.
I managed to remove all the errors but it still won't create additional columns in database.

Comment: Can you give me detail config file

Comment: try installing magento again with your codebase and a clean db. Sometimes these setup files are cached but flushing the cache doesn't help.

Comment: Hello guys,
Martuza - update: above is my complete config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have an extra space in your installer table name.  Please remove space from all shown in below example

From

`getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity '),`

To

`getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity'),`

and also from here

from
`->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity ')`

To

`->addColumn($installer->getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity')`

you have this issue because magento won't find Table name for in that case

and also update your version to 0.0.5 in cofig.xml file like below

```
<modules>
  <EDPA_Adpan>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
  </EDPA_Adpan>
</modules>
```

Comment: already removed, still won't work ;(

Comment: See My updated answer

Comment: Any Update for this ???

Comment: Not yet, just came back home. Will update soon:)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from removing spaces in table's name -

```
getTable('eav/catalog_product_entity')
```

You have written wrong version in your config.xml, use below mentioned one -

```
<modules>
  <EDPA_Adpan>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
  </EDPA_Adpan>
</modules>
```

Also in your database table "**core_resources**", search for module version entry "**adpan_setup**" and delete that. After that browse your website. It will execute upgrade script.